# Evaluating Terminating Condition

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am learning javascript to enhance some of my daily work, and so I am learning the basics.

I am still pretty green with the syntax, but am picking up on the language pretty quickly.

What I am trying to understand is how i can create a terminating condition that is evaluating a function.

I know the coding is wrong here, which is what I am trying to fix - I attempted a bunch of different things, but I am having trouble evaluating the loop based on my product.

I tried using `return` to store the value each iteration, but every attempt resulted in the script flat out failing.

What I want the script to do is to stop the loop when my product reaches <=100.

The problem is, my research suggests that the loop criteria can ONLY be referencing the variable, i.

I'm stuck in terms of how to look at the resulting `product` as the terminating condition.

```
var one = 5;
var two = 10;
var end = 100;

function mult (one, two) {
  var product = one * two;
  document.writeln(product + "<br>");
}

for (var i = 1; i <= end; i++)
  mult(i, two);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your loop to terminate when the product is `<= 100`, use an `if` statement to decide whether you want to write a line.

I've changed some variable names to make it easier to understand.

```js
/*var one = 5;*/ /*This is never being used*/
var ten = 10;
var end = 100;

function mult (a, b){
  var product = a * b;
  if (product <= 100){
    document.writeln(product + "<br>");
   }
}

for (var i = 1; i <= end; i++){
  mult(i, ten);
}
```

Comment: This was exactly the result i was looking for - i just initialized i to 5 to replace var one.

Answer (score 0):

"the loop criteria can ONLY be referencing the variable, i." that's false!

You can define multiple conditions in a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

To access the 'product' variable after loop execution you can declare it in the outer scope of the mult() function (or you can rewrite the mult() function to returns the product variable).

Like this:

```
  var two = 10;
  var end = 100;
  var someNumberGtThan100 = 100000;
  var lastProduct = 0;
  var product = 0;

  function mult (one, two) {
    lastProduct = product;
    product = one * two;
    document.writeln(product + "<br>");
  }

  for (var i = 1; i <= someNumberGtThan100 && product <= 100; i++) {
    mult(i, two);
  }

  console.log(lastProduct); // 100
```

By using this condition you have to store the previous value in an auxiliary variable, because when 'product' reach the value of 100 the loop condition is still true, so the loop will be executed one time more.

Comment: thanks for the input - the first response is much more to my speed, since I am still in the early chapters of my book!